# Java caller can find null character in bytebuffer returned from class but not when iterating through the bytebuffer in the class

Tags: java, char, bytebuffer, null-terminated

I have the following code to go through a `bytebuffer` full of `chars` in `Java` and build a `string`.

```
      StringBuilder actualString = new StringBuilder();

      for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
       {
            if((char)bbuf.get(i) != '\0');
            {
                actualString.append((char)bbuf.get(i));
                System.out.println("ascii code is " + bbuf.get(i));
            }
        }
```

The code works correctly and stops at the `\0` (null terminator) when encountered when the `bytebuffer` was gotten using a caller to the class and iterated through where the caller function is contained.

for example

```
new bufclass = bufclass

buffclass.getbytebuffer

run code from above
```

However when I put that code after the `bytebuffer` is made and allocated in the class where the `bytebuffer` is contained it never stops at a `\0` character.

an example of how this is done would be

```
create bytebuffer and allocate bytebuffer

run code to iterate from above
```

Why is my code working when iterating through the `bytebuffer` using a caller to the class to get the `bytebuffer`, but not working when the code was added to the class containing the `bytebuffer`?

As of note, here is my results when printing out the `ASCII` character codes, and yes I did try `if the byte is equal to 0` which didn't work either.

```
ascii code is 116
ascii code is 101
ascii code is 115
ascii code is 116
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
ascii code is 0
```

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question. Simple sentences, subject verb object. I read your question like three times, and still have no real clue what you are talking about.

Comment: there is a caller that contained the code above, bytebuffer is gotten using caller and works correctly. code was then put in the class where the bytebuffer is contained and made code then doesnt work when used with bytebuffer

Comment: Never put more information in comments. Update the question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a `;` after your if statement:

```
if((char)bbuf.get(i) != '\0');
```

This is functionally equivalent to

```
if((char)bbuf.get(i) != '\0') {
}
```

So, remove that `;` and you'll be good to go.